# Tibco EMS connectivity using nodejs /Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, tibco-ems, stompjs

How we can connect to Tibco from a nodejs environment.

Have anyone tried to connect to Tibco EMS queue using any nodejs package like stompjs or any javascript component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the TIBCO approach for this would be to use the TIBCO [Web Messaging](http://www.tibco.com/products/automation/enterprise-messaging/web-messaging/) product.
This separate module offer a bridge to EMS, callable from Javascript and flash programs. It is meant of extreme scaling of mobile devices.

If you stay with TIBCO solutions, FTL is also an option. This low latency next generation messaging bus can be interfaced with Javascript.

If either of these solutions are not acceptable, you can create a web service responsible of creating messages on the bus. This is of course more difficult for READING out of a queue or subscribing to a topic... but can be done.

And last but not least... other (sometimes free) messaging buses have REST API interfaces. One example is [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response .Do you have Javascript code or example to connect to Tibco?.

Comment: Web messaging is a separate product you or your client might need to buy. So is FTL. A "free" option is to use java or businessworks to host a web service. This web service would write or read to ems... No. I don't have a free example... But you should find what you need in the businessworks 6 (for rest support) tutorials.