# Using Tibco EMS with node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, jms, tibco, tibco-ems

I am working on an app which has recently converted to a node.js back end.

My original plan is to use Tibco EMS to publish messages through a queue, and use websockets to fire these to the front end, however I wanted to know if this is feasible for a relative beginner using node.js? And if so what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIBCO EMS supports the JMS standard but has client libs for various platforms, e.g. C Lib could be used in a custom node module to access EMS. Someone asked the question a while before (see here: [Tibco EMS protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912695/tibco-ems-protocol/37934683#37934683)).

There's an experimental EMS node plugin on github, but not sure if in usable status so far: https://github.com/JensWalter/node-ems

Another option if your company has TIBCO's Web messaging addon for EMS is to use websockets like described here [Tibco EMS connectivity using nodejs /Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947302/tibco-ems-connectivity-using-nodejs-javascript)

Hope that helps